# Is it possible to create a ZIP file with NUL (0 length) password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, zip

I want to know is it possible to create a ZIP file with NUL (0 length) password? If it is possible, how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean a password with a zero length? Where a password dialog appears but is satisfied if you just hit ENTER? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7Zip let's you create ZIP files with an empty password from the command line

```
> "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -p test.zip text.txt
[...]
Enter password (will not be echoed):
Files read from disk: 1
Archive size: 154 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok
```

And it will allow you to extract it as well, even with the GUI. Note that the OK button is enabled

[image: Empty password accepted]

However, the Windows feature "extract all" does not accept empty passwords. Note that the OK button is disabled:

[image: Empty password not accepted]

So, while possible, your clients may have some trouble with an empty password.

An empty password is not allowed on Linux using `zip`.

```
$ zip -e test.zip text.txt
Enter password:    
zip error: Invalid command arguments (zero length password not allowed)

$ zip -P "" test.zip text.txt    
zip error: Invalid command arguments (zero length password not allowed)
```

But it is possible to create an archive using the single character NUL:

```
$ zip -P \0 test.zip text.txt
  adding: text.txt (deflated 23%)

$ unzip -P \0 test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: text.txt
```